# VB.net- Data type mismatch in criteria expression

Tags: vb.net, string

I am trying to add the vote count after the selected user from the ddl.
I Don't see what I did wrong.

```
 Dim str As String
        str = "update [vote] SET [voteweight] = [voteweight]+1 where [userID] = 'DropDownList4.Selectedvalue'"

    Dim Conn As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;; data source=" & Server.MapPath("App_Data/final.mdb"))
    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(str, Conn)
    Conn.Open()
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Conn.Close()
```

Comment: do you have a userid of `"DropDownList4.Selectedvalue"`.  probably not.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to pass a value to an sql command is through a parameterized query. Otherwise the errors that could be embedded in your string are very numerous and subtle.

In your code, the single quotes around the control value, transform everything in a literal string and, of course, the `UserID` field is a numeric field that cannot be compared against a string

```
   if DropDownList4.Selectedvalue = Nothing then
       Return
   End If    

   Dim str = "update [vote] SET [voteweight] = [voteweight]+1 " & _ 
             "where [userID] = @userid"
   Using Conn = New OleDbConnection(.....)
   Using cmd As New OleDbCommand(str, Conn)
       Conn.Open()
       cmd.Parameters.Add("@userid", OleDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(DropDownList4.Selectedvalue)
       cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
   End Using
   End Using
```

Other things to keep present are:

[Using Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh.aspx) around disposable object like the connection and the command (thus avoiding the possibility to leak resources if an exceptions triggers and you forget to dispose them)

A check around the SelectedValue for null is always a good measure. Sometimes your control could loose the Selection and you should be absolutely sure that there is no way to enter this code with a SelectedValue = Nothing.